# Save numbered versions of excel files based on folder contents

Tags: excel, vba

I need code that saves incrementally numbered versions of a file based on whether similarly named files already exist in a specified folder.

For example,

1. Check for the prescence of currently open file, say named
   "Inv_Dec_2015.xlsx" in a folder named "Reports".
2. If file exists, check for "Inv_Dec_2015_v1.xlsx" in "Reports".
3. If file exists, check for "Inv_Dec_2015_v2.xlsx" in "Reports".
4. If file exists, check for "Inv_Dec_2015_v3.xlsx" in "Reports".
5. If file does NOT exist, Save currently open file as "Inv_Dec_2015_v3.xlsx"

and so on till any number of versions......

I found the following two pieces of code on Ron de Bruin's website that can be used for something like this and modified it a bit to my purpose, but I don't know how use it to check for pre-existing files.

Would deeply appreciate any help with this.

```
Sub Rename_Store_Wbk()
    Dim sPath As String

' Enter the path at which file is to be stored

    sPath = ActiveSheet.Range("K1").Value & ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Value & ".xlsx"

' Check whether the file already exists by calling the FileExist function

    If FileExist(sPath) = False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath, _
         FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    End If

End Sub


Function FileExist(FilePath As String) As Boolean

Dim TestStr As String

'Test File Path (ie "C:\Users\Chris\Reports\Inv_Dec_2015.xlsm")
  On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Determine if File exists
  If TestStr = "" Then
    FileExist = False
  Else
    FileExist = True
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: What help are you looking for? Your logic makes sense and you can modify the above code to apply to your situation. Its just a matter of putting in a few loops. You have all the ingredients. What exactly are you looking for from this fourm?

Answer (score 0):

See if the loop I added in here works for you:

```
Sub Rename_Store_Wbk()

    Dim sPath As String

    ' Enter the path at which file is to be stored
    sPath = ActiveSheet.Range("K1").Value & ActiveSheet.Range("K2").Value & ".xlsx"

    If Not FileExists(sPath) Then

        i = 1
        Do

            sPath = Left(sPath, Len(sPath) - 5) & "_v" & i & ".xlsx"
            i = i + 1

        Loop Until FileExists(sPath)

    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath, _
         FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```